# Making download link to DOMPDF generated pdf on same page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, dompdf

I'm making a dynamic html page generated with values from a database. The user has the option to "hide" divs and manipulate other elements on the page. I want to send all the HTML on the page to DOMPDF and have it generate a download link for me.

```
<a href="dl.php">Download</a>
```

Where dl.php would have something like this where the html is sent to DOMPDF and generated:

`$dompdf = new DOMPDF();

$dompdf->load_html($html);

$dompdf->render();

$dompdf->stream("myCV.pdf");`

However since the user is manipulating the DOM on the page and I want to get rid of stuff like links, I'm using jquery to grab the html

```
   $('a').wrap('<span style="display:none;"></span>');
   var fullhtml = $("#body").html();
   fullhtml = encodeURIComponent(fullhtml);
```

annnndd since it's a large page, I can't use GET, have to use POST to send the html. How would I get it so that I can just do a AJAX call with the html to dl.php and just 'include' the page so that it runs? If I return anything from a AJAX call, the pdf file gets converted into text which is a mess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question exactly, but as far as I understand, you're taking the HTML of the page, hiding all the links, and then submitting the whole thing inside a POST request to `dl.php`, right? So `dl.php` would say something like this:

```
$html = urldecode($_POST['html']);
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
//...
```

Right?

You could have the user initiate this process by clicking a link, at which point you populate a form with a hidden input with the processed HTML (links hidden, etc.) before the submission takes place, i.e.:

```
$('a#submit_link').click(function() {
  // wrap links, etc. here
  var html = $("body").html();
  $('#hidden_form_input').val($html);
  $('#hidden_form').submit();
});
```

Something like this should then present your user with the generated PDF.

Comment: thanks, worked perfectly! Such a simple solution, I feel bad for not having figured that out :D

Comment: This is a good answer. Just for those who wants to use button instead of link, remember that the type of button should be "button" and not "submit".