# export the current web page to pdf

Tags: php, mysql, pdf

I want to export my current web page to pdf.In image green and blue color are the web page content and button in red color.when I click pdf button current page will get download as pdf.now I loaded sample text 'sample' in load_html.This text will converted into pdf.I want to load the whole page instead of sample text.

[image]

```
<?php

require_once("dompdf_config.inc.php");

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html("<p>sample</p>");
$dompdf->set_paper('a4', 'portrait');
$dompdf->render();

$dompdf->stream("dompdf_out.pdf"); //for downloading automatically
?>
```

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/convert-html-to-pdf-with-dompdf/

Answer (score 0):

Change this `$dompdf->set_paper('a4', 'portrait');` to this `$dompdf->set_paper('A4');`

Try this

```
require_once("dompdf_config.inc.php");

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();

$dompdf->load_html("<p>sample</p>");
$dompdf->set_paper('A4'); # Changed & No need to mention portrait. This is default
$dompdf->render();

$dompdf->stream("dompdf_out.pdf");
```

> Paper size string like:  **`letter`**, **`legal`**, **`A4`** ....

Comment: I need to integrate this with button click

Comment: [Making download link to DOMPDF generated pdf on same page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987968/making-download-link-to-dompdf-generated-pdf-on-same-page)

Comment: <input type="submit" value="pdf" name="pdf"> If I clicked that button that page can converted into pdf